# Adobe Acrobat DC Pro timesheet JavaScript reading time

Tags: javascript, datetime, adobe, acrobat

I am trying to get this form to count hours worked and for some reason it is counting the time wrong, for instance if you clock in at 8:00 and clock out at 4:00 that should read as 8 hours but the system is reading it as 12 hours. I am very new to JavaScript code but have followed the how to from [here](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/date_time_part1/index.html). This has really not got me anywhere. Attached is how I have the for set up.
Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I have some working code for this but I need to know one thing. Will a student ever work across midnight. In other words, might a shift start at 8:00PM and go to 4:00AM the following day?

Comment: To answer your question, that is a no. We only have students works daytime hours here.